# Jquery code adding/showing divs not working

Tags: jquery

Please help me. Below is my jquery code. I am trying to show #valErrorDiv div  inside the #container div and below #userForm div.

Note: #container is the parent div and it contains ( #userForm,#loadingImg,#valErrorDiv) divs.

This is what I am trying.

1.I am making a ajax request and in before send callback I am hiding #userForm and showing #loadingImg.This works perfectly fine.

2.Now, When I get the server response.Based on some condition from the success callback I am removing #loadingImg div and showing #userForm divs. This works fine.But, I also want to show #valErrorDiv(below the #userForm div).But the #valErrorDiv is appearing and disappearing quickly and I can only see  #userForm div.

Please see the full code at http://jsfiddle.net/yxW8L/2/. Please help me I am breaking my head from last two days. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
            url : "/RestTest/rest/getJson",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : inputdata,
            contentType : "application/json",
            cache : false,
            async:false,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#userForm").hide();
                $("#loadingImg").show();
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.invalidCred) {
                    alert(data.invalidCred);
                    $("#loadingImg").remove();
                    $("#userForm").show();
                    $("#valErrorDiv").show();

                }else {
                    alert(data.SessionID);
                    $("#container").remove();
                    $("#responseDiv").show().append(
                            "<ul><li>" + data.OperatorID
                            + "</li><li>" + data.SessionID
                            + "</li></ul>");
                }
            }
```

Thanks,

Ashu

Comment: can you show your html code. you are removing div '#loadingImg' but when you are adding?

Comment: I am not adding back the #loadingImg div. http://jsfiddle.net/yxW8L/2/. code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't preventing the form from submitting, so it starts your ajax request, then does a normal full-page form submit. Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#userForm").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please point in my code and elaborate where exactly I am doing the full page submit.

Comment: You have a button with `type="submit"`, and you have code that runs when the form's `submit` event fires. Since you aren't preventing the form submit in the submit event handler, the form must be submitting.

Comment: Wow!!!!.. Great!!! thanks a lot for the help.It worked!!. So, now we have prevented the default submit event and ajax call is working. I am right??

Comment: I would assume so, yes. Though I noticed that you are using `async:false`, which is almost always not a good idea, since it locks up the browser. Now that you're preventing the submit, you should be able to change that easily.